# RabbitVCS doesn't have right-click integration with the file manager

Tags: svn, rabbitvcs

I have installed rabbitvcs with apt-get, but nothing appears when I right-click on a versioned folder.

- I've tried logging out and even restarting.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got it to work using the ppa, not the official repos :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa

#don't forget
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
```

... I don't know what's in the official repositories, but it doesn't work.

and you will need to re-read the nautilus config

```
ps auxw|grep nautilus
kill -HUP <processid>
```

or just log out and back in again.

Comment: I has error on Ubuntu 16 when following your guide; error snapshot as http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGaU0.png. May you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I also had to run the command `chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config/rabbitvcs`

Answer (score 0):

One work around, if you are using Pycharm (community edition) like me, is to move the files/folders within the IDE and commit via versioning tool of the IDE.

[image]