# Rabbit vcs is not getting installed. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rabbitvcs

I tried to install Rabbit SVN following this link. I tried all the other links that i got after googling. [rabbit vcs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167431/just-installed-rabbitvcs-but-nothing-changed-in-nautilus)

When i run the third command i am getting the message that rabbit vcs is already the newest version. when i right click on the folders the rabbit vcs option is not showing up.

```
 shanavas@shanavas-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~$ sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    rabbitvcs-nautilus3 is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you restarted nautilus?

Comment: yes i have restarted following this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/19979/how-to-restart-nautilus-without-logging-out