# Rabbitvcs not working with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rabbitvcs

I have followed all the steps to install from following urls:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-rabbitvcs-ubuntu-linux-mint-ppa/

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-rabbitvcs-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint-15-14-13-and-elementary-os-0-2-luna/

http://tutorialforlinux.blogspot.in/2013/08/tutorial-install-rabbitvcs-in-ubuntu.html

[RabbitVCS doesn't have right-click integration with the file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167431/just-installed-rabbitvcs-but-nothing-changed-in-nautilus)

None is working for me. Can anyone please help!!!

Comment: I'd update your question with details on how it is not working. What do you see? What error messages?

Comment: I am not able to see any error message. When i run following command 

shiv.sh@01-01180:~$ rabbitvcs
Usage: rabbitvcs <module> [path1] [path2] ...

Available Modules
------------------

SVN:
    about, add, annotate, applypatch, branch, browser, changes, checkmods, 
    checkout, cleanup, commit, createpatch, create, delete, diff, editconflicts,
    export, ignore, import, lock, log, merge, properties, open, relocate, rename, 
    markresolved, revert, settings, switch, unlock, update, updateto...............

It looks like rabbitvcs is working but I am not able to see options in right click

Comment: I don't think you can tag people if they weren't involved in the thread. That is, illuminace won't get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add problematic PPA s to install `rabbitvcs`. It is in [main Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=rabbitvcs)

Remove the present `rabbitvcs` installation. Then remove the repository. Then install as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-core rabbitvcs-cli
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tries as per your suggestion but still the same problem. It shows rabbitvcs is installed but i am not able to see gui (options on right click of folder) :(